# Is there something like numpy.ascontiguousarray for Pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm selecting and slicing large data frames and I suspect there to be a memory leak.

Is there something like numpy.ascontiguousarray for Pandas?

What strategies can you recommend to track down those memory leaks?

Example:

```
def read_cached_data(file, column_list, row_slice)
   global cache # large pd.DataFrame (over 20 GB)
   if cache is None:
      cache = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=None, ...)

   result = cache[:, column_list]
   result = result[row_slice, :]
```

Comment: There are no memory leaks in Python, since you never get raw access to the objects in memory themselves. The garbage collector automatically takes care of these issues for you.

Comment: How are you selecting and slicing the DataFrames? Can you show some example code?

Comment: @ajcr, I just added some example code

Comment: I think you can save some memory by moving `column_list` into `pd.read_csv(..., usecols=column_list, ...)` instead of slicing

Comment: @MaxU, I would like to not do it, because than I get too many cache misses. Slicing is still faster than reading from hard disk.